# '%' instead of 'px' remove the 'float' effect

Tags: css, css-float, absolute

**Scenario:**
We have an 'absolute' div wrapping the `float:left` elements.

Using `%` instead of `px` is making `float:left` having no effect in this scenario.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4m5x/)

*Check: `div.main_button_box`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float works just fine, it's the size of the parent element that changes.

The parent element gets its size from the child elements. When you change a child element to use percent (which is percent of the parent element), that child can no longer be included when the size of the parent element is calculated. The width of the parent becomes the width of only the other child element, and the second child element floats below the first as the first child takes up the full width of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have not assigned any width for the `div.body` class which is parent for the green color div. I have just assigned 100% for the `div.body` and it is working fine.

```
 div.body {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 20px;
width:100%;

div.main_informations {
    float: left;
    background-color:#49b7e5;
    padding: 20px 45px;

    h1 {
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: white;
    }
}

div.main_button_box {
    //
    // Following 'width: 50px', try to change 50px with 50%.
    // 
    width: 50%;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;

    span {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
}
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4m5x/1/)